# Jupyter notebook seems to remember previous path (!pwd) after being moved to a different directory?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab

I initially had a notebook in one directory in AWS SageMaker JupyterLab, say `/A`, but then moved it into `/A/B`. However, when I run `!pwd` in a jupyter notebook cell, I still get `/A`. This happens even when I press 'restart kernel'. How does the notebook remember this, and is there a way to prevent or reset this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually using AWS SageMaker, and restarting the kernel from the toolbar was not enough. I needed to restart the kernel session, by pressing 'shut down' in the "Running terminals and kernels" section on the left navigation.

[image: Shut down button seen on left navigation of JupterLab]

They are currently [discussing](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5989) warning users about the need to restart the kernel when a notebook is moved.